# Different number of records in gpkg vs. shapefile after join

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, geopackage

I'm using pyqgis 3.10.1.and trying do Spatial join with one-to-many option for points and multipolygon. After processing result shows me too low number of records. I save results to geopackage but when i save the same layer to shapefile the number of records is correct. It's weird... Do you have any clue what could be wrong?

I'm using 'qgis:joinattributesbylocation' algorithm and saving temporary results to memory, then to geopackage or shapefile.

Comment: Very hard to answer without test data and without seeing your code. The format should not matter. Blind guess is that the polygon layer contains both polygons and multipolygons. GeoPackage considers them as different geometry types but shapefile does not. If that is the case there are two options: cast all geometries into multipolygons or create the geopackage layer with a generic geometry type "geometry" so that it accepts all kind of geometries.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  I don't why but fid column in output file has duplicated ids and that's why in geopackage i see only part of output.  Do you have any suggestions how to precalculate before writing to geopackage?